# Many to Many Relation with custom pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I have 4 tables in project's database:

```
users (id, name)
teams (id, name)
team_members (id, user_id, team_id)
team_member_permissions (team_member_id, team_id)
```

I need to get user's teams. My current solution is to create `teamMembers` relationship in `User` model:

```
public function teamMembers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(TeamMember::class);
}
```

`members` relationship in `Team` model:

```
public function members()
{
    return $this->hasMany(TeamMember::class);
}
```

`permissions` relationship in `TeamMember` model:

```
public function permissions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class);
}
```

But how can I optimise it? For example, to get all teams for users I need to use

```
Team::whereHas('teamMember', function($query) use ($user){
    $query->where('user_id', $user->id);
})->paginate();
```

But how can I implement a relationship that will contains all user's teams to get user's teams in one string of code, like `$user->teams`?

Comment: you can just use many to many relations. Is your team_members a pivot table?

Comment: @DeepeshThapa actually no. There's an ID for `team_members` because I need to sync permissions between `TeamMember` and `Team` models.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use many to many relation in regards to your team_members tables to explicitly mention as pivot.

User model:

```
public function teams()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class, 'team_members');
}
```

Team model:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'team_members');
}
```

Since you want to use whereHas clause on teamMember table, I believe that you want to extract teams based on the fact that all teams belonging to that user based on team_members table.

So, You can specify the table name on many to many relation as above.

Now you can use

```
$user->teams
```